# Allow customers to send feedback

Tags: c#, feedback, user-feedback

I thought this would be simpler.  I want to allow users of my software to fill out a feedback form, which would then get emailed to me.

Apparently, this is not as simple as just calling a "Send Email" function.  The user could be anywhere in the world, and as long as they have internet access, I'd like them to have the ability to send me feedback.

What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Did you check the SmtpClient class? it allows you to send e-mails very easily...

Comment: @Gusman: I did, but it requires a server.  If the software is on some anonymous user's machine, I don't know the server.  Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Yes, you are the one who has to have a server, then you connect through your server and your email account. You can create an account with mandrill per example which gives you exactly that, an SMTP account for sending emails.

Comment: Not sure why this was put on hold.  I asked a specific question and it has a very specific answer.  Nothing opinion-based about it.  It's not like I asked a question about global warming.  But apparently this is one of those political questions in stack overflow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gusman got me on the right track.  Instead of using Mandrill, I set up a new gmail account for my application to use as the sender.

I found this and it works beautifully:

[Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have the software generate an email, why not have a button that directs them to a page with a survey or textbox where they can submit feedback. That seems like the simplest solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a code answer but we use Machform a lot. Really awesome tool to build forms.

It's just $50 bucks. Has email, download support etc.

http://www.appnitro.com/

Worth a check!